# Amazon EC2 Elastic Load Balancer TCP disconnect after couple of hours

Tags: sockets, tcp, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, disconnect

I am testing the reliability of TCP connections using Amazon Elastic Load Balancer compared to not using the Load Balancer to see if it has any impact.

I have setup a small Elastic Load Balancer on Amazon EC2 us-east zones with 8 t2.micro instances using an auto scaling group without policy and set to 8 min/max instance.

Each instance run a simple TCP server that accept connections on port 8017 and relay some data to the clients coming from another remote server located in my network. The same data is send to all clients.

For the purpose of the test, the servers running on the micro instances are only sending 1 byte of data every 60 seconds (to be sure the connection don't time out).
I connected multiple clients from various outside networks using the ELB DNS name provided, and after maybe 6-24 hours, I always stop receiving data and eventually the connections all die.

All clients stops around the same time, even though they are on different network/ISP. Each "client" application is doing about 10 TCP connections and they all stop receiving data.

All server instances look fine after this happen, they still send data.
To do further testing and eliminate the TCP server code problem, I also have external clients connected directly to the public IP of a single instance, without the ELB, and the data doesn't stop and the connection is not lost in this case (so far).

The Load balancer Idle Timeout is set to 900 seconds.
The Cross-Zone load balancing is enabled and I am using the following zones: us-east-1e, us-east-1b, us-east-1c, us-east-1d

I read the documentation, and searched everywhere to see if this is a known behaviour, but I couldn't find any clear answer or confirmation of others having the same issue, but it seems clear it is happening in my case.

My question: Is this a known/expected behaviour for TCP load balancer? Otherwise, any idea what could be the problem in my setup?